# XSD: Divide scheme using a choice of sequences

Tags: xsd

A part of my xsd looks as follows:

```
<xs:element name="my_element" minOccurs="1 maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="sequence_1" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="ID1" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="TYPE1" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="sequence_2" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="ID2" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="TYPE2" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>   
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The first element name of the sequence decides about th following nodes.
If I now have a lot of different sequences with some elements inside my xsd doesn't look very clear.

Is it possible to separate the sequences (like I can do it for complexType)?

Comment: Question is not really clear. Do you mean use of "group" ? (yes there is group of element)

Comment: oh that was easier than I thought. sorry for the bad question, but you found the solution. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use group :

```
<xs:group name="seqGroup_x">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="sequence_x" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
        ...
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="yourType">
    <xs:group ref="seqGroup_x"/>
    <xs:attribute name="anotherattr" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```